# Kurento Media Server HelloWorld Javascript example webSocket error

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, websocket, kurento

Merry Christmas!

I am trying to configure KMS on my Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit). I could install the KMS server successfully following the guide at https://www.kurento.org/docs/6.0.0/installation_guide.html.

Also, downloaded the Javascript HelloWorld tutorial from https://www.kurento.org/docs/6.0.0/tutorials/js/tutorial-1-helloworld.html. I could run the example successfully on localhost on Google Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit) on the same Ubuntu System.

But, I could not see the local video nor the loop backed video. Only a spinner icon is shown on both the Video placeholders. Consulting the Console log reveals a problem after creating the SDP offer. The error is as described below.

**kurento-client.js:21072 WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:8433/kurento' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

I am no expert on web sockets and stuff. Any help on this would really help me to proceed forward.

Note: I am running the example on HTTP, not on HTTPS. I guess that would not be the cause of the problem, though.

Regards,

LazyCoder7

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it. I was wrong on my guess though, HTTPS was indeed required in order to make the WebSocket connection ( i was not aware of that part ). Created a certificate file (.pem) (from crt and key file already in the helloworld folder) and configured the KMS server to use the certificate. After this I was able to see myself and the same me in loopback :)

Comment: How did you solve the problem? I have a very similar problem to yours. I created the .pem certificate, but I do not have the three files as in the tutorial (signing-ca.crt subordinate-ca.crt server.crt)

Comment: The files are already in the git repo. https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-js/tree/master/kurento-hello-world/keys

Comment: All three of them need to be concatenated into a .pem file? Is there any order to be followed for the concatenation (which file is first, second, third). Also how can this file be generated if I use a certificate authority (e.g., Lets Encrypt)

Answer (score 0):

You are following an old version of the documentation. Since Chrome 47, in is mandatory to server pages through HTTPS if you want to use the `getUserMedia` APi. So we updated all our tutorials, and they now have a self-signed certificate. In case of the JS tutorials, you also need to configure KMS to expose a secure WS signalling connection, as the browser directly connects to the media server to control it.

Please follow the latest version of the documentation [here](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorials/js/tutorial-1-helloworld.html)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the KMS is running on the port 8433 (not 8888), if you are using docker

```
docker run -d --name kms -p 8433:8433 kurento/kurento-media-server:trusty-latest
```